# 2 models, 1 'array' in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app (news site) that displays articles. Now I have 2 models: `Article` and `Video`. Both models should be shown chronologically (based on `created_at`) in a `@news_items` array. Is this possible by default in Rails? Preferably without any Ruby sort methods.

Many thanks!

Comment: are these two models related to each other ?

Comment: They are related in a way that they share some properties, so they have a `title` and `description`, but they are different models.

Comment: He means `associations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your models are not related through some kind of association (`has_many`, `belongs_to`), then it's not possible.

It's not possible to achieve what you want on plain SQL level, so even if ActiveRecord provided such functionality, it would have to generate 2 SQL queries and then sort results using Ruby `sort` method.